# ¿WebView en un Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, webview

Tengo este error:

> Second_Fragment cannot be converted to Fragment

Código:

```
public class Second_fragment extends Fragment {

    String direccion_web = "https://www.google.es/";

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_tab,container,false);

        WebView appWeb = (WebView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.webView);
        //Habilitamos el javaScript y el zoom
        appWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        appWeb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        //Cargamos el enlace definido
        appWeb.loadUrl(direccion_web);
        //Este método es para que el navegador se quede en nuestra aplicación
        appWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

second_tab.xml : 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="304dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

¿Qué es lo que falla? ¿No se puede implementar esto en un Fragment?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BottomBar mBottomBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mBottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);
        mBottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.menu_main, new OnMenuTabSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMenuItemSelected(@IdRes int i) {

                if (i == R.id.one) {

                    First_fragment f1 = new First_fragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,f1).commit();

                }

                if (i == R.id.two) {

                    Second_fragment f2 = new Second_fragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, f2).commit();

                }

                if (i == R.id.three) {

                    Three_fragment f3 = new Three_fragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, f3).commit();

                }
                if (i == R.id.four) {

                    Four_fragment f4 = new Four_fragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, f4).commit();
                }
                if (i == R.id.five) {

                    Five_fragment f5 = new Five_fragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, f5).commit();

                }
            }
        });
        mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(0, "#c92029");
        mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(1, "#c92029");
        mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(2, "#c92029");
        mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(3, "#c92029");
        mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(4, "#c92029");
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar donde llamas a este fragment?

Comment: He actualizado la entrada. Lo llamo en el segundo if. Es un bottomBar

Comment: Tengo que poner extends Fragment sí o sí , pues si no, en el MainActivity que acabo de actualizar, se me queja. Es un BottomBar ( QUE ESTOY DESEANDO PODER PONER ACTIVITYS EN VEZ DE FRAGMENTS ) pues me da muchísimos problemas, como este...

Comment: Revisa si tus _imports_ estén de esta manera `import  android.support.v4.app.Fragment `

Comment: He Actualizado todo mi Main, lo que os decía... Me gustaría poner que no fuera Fragment, pero un BottomBar sin Fragment no he encontrado y me da muchos problemas para todo... y llevo de horas perdidas...

Comment: ¿Ya has revisado lo que te dije en mi comentario anterior?

Comment: Sí, lo tengo así y ahora se me ejecuta en el móvil, pero se me detiene la aplicación.

Comment: Estoy 100 % seguro que es por el Fragment, en mi anterior pregunta a esta, tiene que ver con Fragment, me limita mucho.... en el MainActivity, no puedo ponerlo de alguna forma para poder poner FragmentActivity y poder expandir mis posibilidades?

Comment: Es decir, cambiar esto :  Second_fragment f2 = new Second_fragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, f2).commit();  Por algo que sea similar para poder poner extends FragmentActivity

Comment: para empezar... yo cambiaria la linea donde buscas el webview desde el fragmento.... preferiria hacerlo con la vista, ya que el margen de error es menor... `WebView appWeb = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);` y has intentado extender de  `FragmentActivity`?

Comment: Si Pongo FragmentActivity, se me queja en el MainActivity la parte de Second_Fragment, concretamente donde poner "f2" .

Comment: @GermanAlzateMartinez +1 para ti. Realmente me ha funcionado lo de poner "v" en vez de getActivity(), mañana miraré si mis otros fallos son también esto. Gracias. De todas formas, Fragments no compensa...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No esta reconociendo tu clase como fragmento.

Cuando inflas el layout del Fragmento, debes obtener las referencias del elemento dentro del Fragmento, en este caso el WebView, no dentro de la Activity.

```
 WebView appWeb = (WebView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.webView); //* INCORRECTO
```

Asegura que tu WebView se encuentre dentro de `second_tab.xml`

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_tab,container,false);

    //* INCORRECTO: WebView appWeb = (WebView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.webView);
     WebView appWeb = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView); //CORRECTO.

    //Habilitamos el javaScript y el zoom
    appWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    appWeb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    //Cargamos el enlace definido
    appWeb.loadUrl(direccion_web);
    //Este método es para que el navegador se quede en nuestra aplicación
    appWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });


    return v;
}
```

Comment: Elena, tal como has puesto, era v.finViewById, y ya me ha funcionado, pero sigo teniendo el problema gordo, mi anterior pregunta a esta que es la de una ListView, puedes echarle un ojo ? Está muy completa, no sé si puede ser este mismo fallo o que... es un Fragment también.

Comment: Claro que sí @RfMvs echaré un vistazo!, saludos.